# What Raspberry Pi would be the best to host these Discord bots?

Tags: server, raspberry-pi, discord

Because the country is in lockdown and we are learning from home, we can't go to college to use raspberry pi there, I can't spare money to get one and I also don't have anything I could use to build a project with it, so I asked if I can host a discord bot that I'm working on for fun on the pi and professor told me to do an analysis of various pi's and various version of the bot to find with what I could get away when choosing to host one. So here is a hypothetical situation:
There are 3 bots: A-fun bot, B-moderation bot, C-fun bot with DB,

- Bot A: Has commands like !blackjack that uses reactions and embeds to portray the game, cards are represented by their number values and various others. Can play music off Youtube by using ytdl, has skip, stop and other commands, has queues, also the bot can get images and jokes from various site API's with axios.
- Bot B: Basic moderation bot, no fun or music commands.
- Bot C: Has the same commands as Bot A, except it also connects to mongoDB and stores user data there, thus it also has economy.

My questions are:

- What kind of Raspberry would I need to host either of these bots?
- Could I get away with Raspberry Pi Zero for Bot B?
- How many servers could the bots be in before it crashes, how many
  people?

I understand that it all depends on the dataflow and how many interactions it has to handle, but the more input I can get on this the better.
***Note:*** All of these hypothetical bots are written using Node.js

Comment: does bot `b` have a word filter (auto deletes messages with certain words)?

Comment: Lets say yes, maybe even add Bot Ba, that doesn't have this kind of functionality

Comment: are you planning on sharding?

Comment: @FBISurveillanceVan I'd like to avoid going too in-depth in this, at least until I have something to show to the professor. So I will skip on sharding part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*note: I write bots in python, so these estimates may be a little off.*

In general, a simple discord connection does not use very many resources (eg. moderation commands that are used occasionally.) More servers does **not** require more processing power, but one can assume that a bot being in more servers will lead to an increase in bot usage.

Making more requests via HTTP and receiving more requests over the gateway will increase resource consumption. Auto-deleting messages may increase resource usage more than expected.

**As for bot `B(a)`(no message filter), you could probably get away with a raspberry pi `0`/`0w` for 10-20 servers. Bot `B(b)`(has message filter) will require more RAM and CPU power. I would recommend a Raspberry Pi `2` for the word filter.**

Writing games using Discord results in *many* requests for reactions, editing messages, and possibly an AI. I am not sure how the economy works on bot `C`, but using MongoDB should not take too much additional CPU power. Depending on the number of servers it is in, you may want a faster SD card and more RAM.

**For bots `A` and `C`, it really depends on how much it is used. A small bot (active use in 1-2 servers) would probably only need 1gb of ram. For a lager bot, I would recommend investing in 2+ GB of ram, especially for bot `C`. If you are planning on making one of the "fun" bots public, I would recommend at *least* 4 GB ram. **

#### **Alternative Option:**

most small (<10 servers) bots can be run on a decent computer (eg. dual core 2ghz, 8gb ram) with no significant performance reduction.

#### TL;DR:

Pi0 will work for bot `Ba`. Get more ram/a better processor for bot `Bb`. I recommend 2gb if private, 4gb if public RAM for bot `A`/`C`, a faster processor for bot `C` especially. *most* discord bots will not crash unless you are absolutely straining the hardware.

**a raspberry pi 4 (8gb) could probably run all three bots at once**

Comment: 8GB?? Good lord, what kind of code is that! We can run 4 bots in JDA on top of a resource-heavy Minecraft proxy (caching player & chunk data) on just 2GB RAM

Comment: it might be a bit overkill, but 8gb will definitely be able to run them all. It also depends on which language/library you are using

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe get away with a Pi Zero W if your doing a basic bot, but I would recommend a Pi 3 or a Pi 4 for more advanced bots. It can also depend on how much data you are storing. You can try using the PIs power itself or use repl on chromium on the pi.

You would need a high storage SD Card for DBs and unexpected growth.

If your using a pi4 with more than 2gb of ram you could get around 75 servers with a very good network connection. With a pi3 you can maybe get 40 servers. With a pi zero w around 15 servers. A lot of this depends on the cpu and the network connection. This is guessing that each server has around 100 people.

TL;DR - Pi Zero W for basic bots, Pi 3 or 4 for more advanced bots.